# Difference beetween normal and boost mode render in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm testing boost mode in highcharts and cant get some of the styling to work when webGL render is on. Small example, this is normal mode with `boost.useGPUTranslations = false`:

[image: with boost.useGPUTranslations = false]

Everything is fine and the way I set it up. Next screenshot is the same chart with same options except `boost.useGPUTranslations = true`:

[image: with boost.useGPUTranslations = true]

Is this an intended behaviour or am I doing something wrong?
I'm using latest `"highcharts": "^7.0.1"` npm module.

BTW the legend is displayed correct, the way lines should be.

[image: legend with boost.useGPUTranslations = true]

Comment: Hi @Dimanoid, This problem looks like a bug, so I reproduced it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e6f82q7u/ and reported on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9799